# Mongodb: Query by distinct ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

using the pymongo package I am trying to query my mongo database to return each distinct `websiteId` where `newStatus` is equal to 7.

```
for i in db.mycollection.find({'newStatus': 7}).distinct('websiteId'):
    pprint(i)
```

Unfortunatley this gives me a `TypeError: 'ObjectId' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`
because `websiteId` appears to be some sort of ObjectId thing:

```
c = db.mycollection.find_one()
pprint(c)

{u'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 22, 20, 31, 58, 316000),
 u'newStatus': 7,
 u'oldStatus': 6,
 u'websiteId': ObjectId('4f94c64578a62')}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

try if this works -

```
connection = pymongo.Connection('mongodb://localhost',safe=True)
db = connection.test
sample = db.sample
query = '\'webstatId\',{"siteId" : "27"}'

try:
    print query
    doc = sample.distinct(query);
except:
    print "Unexpected error", sys.exec_info()[0]
for d in doc:
    print d
```

I tried this in shell -

```
db.sample.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5333764486bee74e9de524ff"), "webstatId" : ObjectId("5333764486bee74e9de524fe"), "siteId" : "27" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5333767a86bee74e9de52500"), "webstatId" : ObjectId("5333764486bee74e9de524fe"), "siteId" : "28" }

db.sample.distinct('webstatId',{"siteId" : "27"})
[ ObjectId("5333764486bee74e9de524fe") ]
```